# Batman Beyond: Terry's Fighting Skills

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe, batman-beyond

For most of the series "Batman Beyond", Terry McGinnis has relatively poor or basic fighting skills. He can overcome simple thugs but lacks the skill and discipline to take on skilled martial artists. Sometimes I think that he would lose a fight against old Bruce Wayne.

Bruce Wayne is one of the most skillful martial artists and is sometimes described as having the best fighting skills for a human in the DC universe.

Throughout the series, Bruce Wayne gives Terry pieces of advice through the comm-link but I never saw him training Terry in martial arts. For example: in "Return of the Joker" film, Terry is unable to overcome the semi-human hyena while old Bruce Wayne waits patiently for the right moment and then strikes him down with his walking cane.

My question is if and when Terry McGinnis goes through proper fighting and martial arts training to become a skilled fighter? In the after-series continuity, does Terry become a master in martial arts like Bruce Wayne did?

Comment: _"Sometimes I think that [Terry] would lose a fight against old Bruce Wayne."_: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z65aq1EVGhs

Comment: He fought a robot disguised as Batman, not the real Bruce Wayne, and even them - it was cunning old Bruce who delivered the killing blow ("Ignite!").

Answer (score 8, accepted):

During the *Batman Beyond* series, there's the episode *[Terry's Friend Dates a Robot](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Terry%27s_Friend_Dates_a_Robot)* during which you can see Bruce Wayne actually training him to fight against robots, in a simulated fight against some of Bruce's old rogue gallery (The Riddler, Two Face, Killer Croc):

Also, in episode *[Curse of the Kobra](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Curse_of_the_Kobra)*, Bruce also sends him into meeting with [Kairi Tanaga](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Kairi_Tanaga), whom Bruce knew from when he trained with [the same master](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Yoru) before becoming Batman, so that Terry could learn to fight more efficiently:

It's more than likely that Bruce would continuously train him into becoming a better Batman, in order to increase his likelihood of staying alive.

It's questionable whether or not he became a master in martial arts like Bruce was, but we get a glimpse of how easily he took care of [Shriek](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Shriek) in the *[Justice League Unlimited](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Justice_League_Unlimited_(animated_series))* episode titled *[Epilogue](https://dcau.fandom.com/wiki/Epilogue)*, when he became a grown up man, long after the timeline of *Batman Beyond*:

On a more trivial note: there used to be a video on Youtube showcasing how Bruce (as Batman), always took out enemies coming from behind him by hitting them with his fist (which the video called his signature move). In a *Batman Beyond* episode, as Bruce was tending Terry's wound, the latter complained that he doesn't have eyes in his back.

Later on, in an unidentified sequence, Terry (as Batman) knocked out a bad guy who tried to jump him from behind, showing he actually learned from Bruce.

Comment: There's another episode in which Bruce actually sends Terry into training for martial arts. I'm just trying to find the links to source the answer.